# How to use WebView inside a Fragment l?

Tags: android, fragment

Hi guys i have a Question.
How to use a `WebView` inside a `Fragment`?
I Know how to use a `WebView` in an `Activity` but i don't know how to do this in a `Fragment`.
Because you cannot use `FindViewById` in a `Fragment`.

Thanks for help

Flo Reich

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a look at [ask].

Comment: Please answer my Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your `onCreateView` like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    WebView webview = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webview_id);
    // other stuff
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped me :-) Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You **can** use `findViewById()` method in *Fragment*. For example, in *onCreateView* method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragmentView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment, container, false);

    // and you can use findViewById() method on fragmentView

    View v = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.your_view);
    ... 
    return fragmentView;
}
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Have a nice day